# Gitignore and commit history issues

Tags: gitignore, smartgit, unreal

I'm starting a new project in unreal engine, using smartgit, and the first thing i did was make a gitignore, although for reasons i'm not clear on, it doesn't seem to have worked, and i didn't notice.

I then did a bunch more commits of coding work, all on the master branch, there are no others yet, but these commits also happened to include some very large autogenerated files that should have been excluded by gitignore. I didn't notice this until i finally tried to push on the fourth commit. It's getting rejected due to large files, which makes sense

Deleting those files and making another commit doesnt help, because they're still part of the history. How can I edit history to make it like they were never included? They are pretty easy to find, its just two folders in the project directory

i cant get the rest of the project committed until i can get this poison out of it

Comment: look up the [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Comment: We've had this problem before and used git-filter-branch (with we'd known about BFG that @2e0byo pointed out) but a potentially easier solution, provided you only have a single commit per offending file otherwise it's more cumbersome, is to interactive rebase while amending the offending commit, unstaging and discarding the large files, deleting them from disk and then continuing rebase. Once this is done, push to main and it should no longer complain about the large files.